# are "Unidirectional" and "Bidirectional" terms belong to OOP world or database world? is everything in Database bi-directional?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm trying to learn about JPA and Hibernate and I was trying to learn about some database terms.

I've question about "Unidirectional" and "Bidirectional" terms. when I search on internet, I see some posts and some articles that use these two terms for 'entity' and 'object'. so I assumed that these two words belong to OOP world.

ok. but in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf1vwRpHNW0), the teacher (at 1:49) said:

> everything in Database is is bi-directional. because based on Foreign
> key, you can reach the value from either side.

so it means that we can use Unidirectional and Bidirectional in database too. right?
but I think the quote from the teacher is not right. because if we have `tableA` which has a foreign key to `tableB` and `tableB` does not have any foreign key to tableA, then it is Unidirectional because we cannot navigate and go from a `tableB`'s record to a `tableA`'s record.

Could you please help me with this issue? thank you

### Edit:

**PS**: can we say if we use `JOIN`, we can say that the teacher is right? If for example the Person class would have a table which holds a foreign key that references the address table, then only the person table will know about the address. The address table will know about the person table only if it joins the table

Comment: Your thinking is object relational. In the database, you know the schema, so if you have a foreign key somewhere, you also know it references your table's ID, and can use that ID to reverse lookup rows with foreign keys that have that value. There really is nothing overly special about a foreign key - it is just a value, like the one it references, with a bit more DB magic to enforce constraints that it actually references something. In the object world, there is no such contract. A person may reference some object, but that reference object has no contract or method to know it is referenced.

Comment: If you have a record of tableB then you can find tableA records where fereign key is of tableB's. I think thats she said 'everything in Database is is bi-directional' which is true. Even JPA internal do the same thing.

Comment: @KetanSuthar would you please give me a query as an example for this?

Comment: It sounds shady to me. Those terms should qualify the relationship between two subjects. In this case the subjects are tables. The relationship is a FK constraint and it’s unidirectional because the table referenced has no dependency with  the table referencing it and at those conditions the reverse lookup is more expensive computationally speaking. In ORM you can declare the inverse side of the relationship and that makes it bidirectional. Anyway those terms are general and describe the dependency

Comment: Any approach at explaining you what a FK is, doesn’t address unidirectional and bidirectional at their core and that’s the essence of your question I guess

Comment: @Chris when you say ***if you have a foreign key somewhere, you also know it references your table's ID, and can use that ID to reverse lookup rows with foreign keys that have that value.***, you mean with *join*? would please give me a query as an example?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita but the reverse lookup is possible using **join**. right? and do you agree with that if we use join, we can say it's some kind of bidirectional? because then we can navigate from each side to another side.

Comment: @TomWard yes the join would work like that but the "binding" is declared inside the "parent" table only while the child doesn't have any information about that. And you have no way to get to the parent table from the child table alone. I'll make it more clear. This whole talk about those 2 terms is about associations declared in an ORM model. Those have the property to be unidirectional or bidirectional in the sense that you can access each side from the other one without performing a new query or not and without tricks beyond the relationship itself.

Comment: A relationship is bidirectional if both the entities involved have a reference to each other. Otherwise is unidirectional. Remaining in those terms the single FK is unidirectional because the child table doesn't have a reference to the parent unless you do a FK on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that strictly speaking 'everything is bi-directional in the database' is not right. A relation between classes is bi-directional if A has a reference to B, and B has a reference to A. If a relation is uni-directional, one side does not even know about the existence of the other.

A foreign key reference is by definition in one direction: table A references table B. B does not know about A at all. In my opinion, it would be bi-directional if B would have a foreign key relation to A as well. The latter might in many cases be redundant or even unwanted, which you tend to get rid of in database design, but in principle exactly the same is true for relations between objects.
"give me the parent with child X" gives the same result as "Child X give me your parent". If the relation is bi-directional, you can get an answer to these questions directly, you can navigate from both sides. But I can see that one might see it differently depending on how you interpret, or what you are trying to say with "bi-directional". I'm curious to read such an interpretation if anyone has one.

What is true is that a bi-directional one-to-many relation (many-to-one on the other side, e.g.: parent knows their children, children know their parent) with Hibernate will result in just a single foreign key relation in the database, since that is sufficient to resolve both sides of the relation. But I personally wouldn't call that bi-directional from a database perspective.

Comment: when table A references table B and B does not know about A at all, we can answer those two question using ***JOIN***. right? so with this interpretation, maybe it's ok to say it is bidirectional. right?

Comment: @TomWard not really. JOIN is an instruction that uses relations between entities to combine data from different tables. Uni- or bi-directionality is a _property_ of relations between entities. They are separate concepts. You can answer the question with a JOIN, but B *still* doesn't know about A so the relation is uni-directional. Just because _you_ can execute an instruction that answers the question, doesn't change the fact that the relation is uni-directional.

Comment: @TomWard if the relation on table-level is bi-directional, then you would be able to join from *both* sides, and not just one side. There would be two different JOIN queries that would give the same result. If it is uni-directional, there is only one way to JOIN the tables, this is why the bi-directional relation between tables is redundant.